# Skyrim: Aggressive NPCs

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm playing Elder Scrolls: Skyrim as a Khajiit and whenever I enter Fort DawnGuard to start the DawnGuard dlc, the NPCs present there are attacking me; Isran and that other guy. It only happens when I enter inside the Fort, the guard standing at the entrance is not getting aggroed.

I've googled the above problem and I've seen that this problem might arise if I got any crime records in Riften, but  I've got a clean sheet in all the provinces.

As for the mods, I'm only using the Moonlight Tales: Essentials and yes, I  can transform into a werewolf.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

I don't think it matters, but I'm wearing the Thieves' Guild armor set.

Comment: You try disabling the mod?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because most of the time it's quite impossible to know exactly why Skyrim behaves the way it does, I assembled a few possible culprits and/or solutions from various sources:

- > **You might have the cursed Ring of Hircine**: if so, you need to finish
  >   that quest first [i.e. '[Ill Met by Moonlight](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Ill_Met_by_Moonlight)']
  >   <sup>[source](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:754205#14)</sup>
- > **I be[a]t them up for a long while, leveled up, ran away to the top,
  >   waited for 24 hours, slept for 24 hours, entered unarmed, and they
  >   weren’t hostile**
  >   <sup>[source](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:754205#15)</sup>
- > On my third attempt to get Dawnguard working, Durak asked me to go the
  >   fort. When I got there, Durak and everyone attacked me and the quest
  >   was broken because the quest-giver would not stop attacking me long
  >   enough to give me the quest. On my machine, **I was able to fix this by
  >   deactivating Dawnguard and making a clean save and starting the quest
  >   over again.**
  >   <sup>[source](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/758566-dawnguard-hostile-on-startup/#entry6095409)</sup>
- > I had this problem ...half way through my dawnguard quests they became
  >   hostile to me, so I just ran before Lydia killed any of them ... I
  >   figured the problem was I had killed some guards earlier, and even
  >   though it said my bounty was removed, it glitched the Dawnguard...**so
  >   my fix is go to Riften, punch a guard, pay the 40 gold, and all is
  >   forgiven**
  >   <sup>[source](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/758566-dawnguard-hostile-on-startup/#entry6843519)</sup>
- > **I fixed it by saving outside the entrance to the Vale, exiting the
  >   game, disabling Dawnguard mod, load up, immediately make a fresh save,
  >   exit, re-enable Dawnguard mod, then load once more.**
  >   <sup>[source](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/63650818#7)</sup>

The solution with the most potential seems to be the following one, however, using the console:

- > I was having the same problem, Isran and Tolan attacking me as soon as
  >   I entered the fort proper. 
  >   To anyone else having this problem, **add Tolan to your
  >   faction**:
  >
  > "*`Addtofaction 0005A1A4 1` adds an NPC to the player ally faction, which
  >   will make a normally hostile NPC no longer hostile towards the
  >   player.*"
  >   <sup>[source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim))</sup>
  >
  > Targeted Tolan in the console, used that command, and I am now good to
  >   go.
  >   <sup>[source](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/63650818)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @Joachim. I haven't began any quests related to the Dawnguard, so the first four solutions you listed didn't work. But the last solution completely solved the issue. Thanks again for your effort.